# ERROR ITMS-90086 Missing 64-bit support Xcode 6.4 and Cordova 2.9.1

Tags: cordova

PLATFORM AND VERSION
iOS
Configuration are as following.
1. Xcode version:6.4
2. IOS device OS version : 8.4
3. Mac OS version:10.10.4
In current project Mobile app build setting ->Valid Architecture: armv7 armv7s amr64 for fields 'Release' and 'Debug'.

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM
We have developed iOS apps for iPhone device using Cordova 2.9.1. App has been validated successfully, but not able to upload for BETA testing using testflight. When 'submit to app store' button clicked from Xcode,
Error pops up saying 'Archive submission failed with error as following.
Error description: 'ERROR ITMS-90086 “Missing 64-bit support” Beginning on February 1........'.

Tried changing Valid Architectures but still same issue.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
1. Archive the app.
2. Validate the apps successfully.
3. Clicked on button 'submit to app store' from Xcode 6.4 then it show error.
'ERROR ITMS-90086 “Missing 64-bit support” Beginning on February 1........'

Comment: Only update cordova, I have updated cordova 3.8.0 from cordova 2.9.1 using node.js command line.

Answer (score 0):

Only update cordova, I have updated cordova 3.8.0 from cordova 2.9.1 using node.js command line.Steps to update cordova.
1.Install node.js
2.Add all Plugins.
3.Build through command.
4.open in xcode and install into device.

Note:I have published sucessfully.